# Separating a column(Variable to two new variable columns

Tags: r

```
   ...1         Frequency         Date         
   <chr>        <chr>             <chr>        
 1 NA           Day of Date...536 July 12, 2021
 2 CasesNumbers Day of Date...536 3.0          
 3 NA           Day of Date...537 July 13, 2021
 4 CasesNumbers Day of Date...537 2.0          
 5 NA           Day of Date...538 July 14, 2021
 6 CasesNumbers Day of Date...538 10.0         
 7 NA           Day of Date...539 July 15, 2021
 8 CasesNumbers Day of Date...539 10.0         
 9 NA           Day of Date...540 July 16, 2021
10 CasesNumbers Day of Date...540 20.0
```

I have data frame which has three variables,
I am trying to change (..1 )column to case numbers
Column date separated by date/case number
I am unsure how to go about this.

```
...1         Frequency         Date         
   <chr>        <chr>             <chr>        
 1 NA           Day of Date...536 July 12, 2021
 2 CasesNumbers Day of Date...536 3.0          
 3 NA           Day of Date...537 July 13, 2021
 4 CasesNumbers Day of Date...537 2.0          
 5 NA           Day of Date...538 July 14, 2021
 6 CasesNumbers Day of Date...538 10.0         
 7 NA           Day of Date...539 July 15, 2021
 8 CasesNumbers Day of Date...539 10.0         
 9 NA           Day of Date...540 July 16, 2021
10 CasesNumbers Day of Date...540 20.0
```

so far I have tried

```
str_split_fixed(df1$`Number of Cases`, ", ", 2)
df1 %>% separate(`Number of Cases`, into = 'Date','Number')
df1 %>% separate(`Number of Cases`, into = 'Date','CasesNumbers')
```

I am really new to R, this may be a silly question, but I am unsure how to go about it

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(Case_Number = as.integer(lead(Date))) %>% 
  slice(seq(1, nrow(.), by = 2)) %>% 
  select(Case_Number, Frequency, Date)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Case_Number Frequency         Date         
        <int> <chr>             <chr>        
1           3 Day of Date...536 July 12, 2021
2           2 Day of Date...537 July 13, 2021
3          10 Day of Date...538 July 14, 2021
4          10 Day of Date...539 July 15, 2021
5          20 Day of Date...540 July 16, 2021
```

### Data

```r
data <- structure(list(...1 = c(NA, "CasesNumbers", NA, "CasesNumbers", 
NA, "CasesNumbers", NA, "CasesNumbers", NA, "CasesNumbers"), 
    Frequency = c("Day of Date...536", "Day of Date...536", "Day of Date...537", 
    "Day of Date...537", "Day of Date...538", "Day of Date...538", 
    "Day of Date...539", "Day of Date...539", "Day of Date...540", 
    "Day of Date...540"), Date = c("July 12, 2021", "3.0", "July 13, 2021", 
    "2.0", "July 14, 2021", "10.0", "July 15, 2021", "10.0", 
    "July 16, 2021", "20.0")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Martin Gal, that worked . I am so very grateful for your help.

Comment: (1) For your next question take a look at the link Ronak posted. Providing data in the structure format, as seen in my answer, makes it so much easier to answer your question and increases your chances to find a solution. (2) And: feel free to accept the answer. ;-)